# How to add child in loop as a userId in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add schema where i have list of ids and value as a date. but I am getting the schema like this:

[image: please follow this image].

But I want in place of 0 is userID and date as a object. Please have a look over my code:

```
final String idGroup = (StaticConfig.UID + System.currentTimeMillis()).hashCode() + "";
final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
Room room = new Room();
for (String id : listIDChoose) {
  AddGroupUser addGroupUser = new AddGroupUser();
  addGroupUser.date = currentDate;
  addGroupUser.user = id;
  room.member.add(addGroupUser);
}
room.groupInfo.put("name", gName);
room.groupInfo.put("admin", StaticConfig.UID);
room.groupInfo.put("avatar",image);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("group/" + idGroup).setValue(room).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        ToastMessage("Group Created");
   }
});
```

How to change my object so that i can get the following result. Any help will be very grateful. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share your `AddGroupUser` and `Room` classes? I think you have a `List<MemberInfo>` in there now, and that'll need to become a `Map<String, MemberInfo>` so that you can set the key.

Comment: Thanks!! That was the mistake which I was doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Room` class you have a `List< AddGroupUser>`. And Firebase translates a `List` to zero-based indexes in the JSON format.

To be able to control the key, the list needs to become a `Map<String, AddGroupUser>`. Then you can set the key of each `AddGroupUser` that you put in the map.

```
room.members.put(id, addGroupUser);
```